# JavaScript function syntax? export default ({...}) => (<View .... >)

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, destructuring

In [this ReactVR example](https://github.com/nikgraf/webvr-experiments), I see this syntax:

```
export default ({ style }) => (
  <View style={style}> ...
)
```

I have done some ES6/TypeScript but this doesn't seem like anything to me.

What does it do? Is it React or JSX specific? (I am new to these two, searched but didn't find.)

Also, how would that be converted to a normal class-based component?

Comment: After getting the answer, I am removing ReactJS from the title.

Comment: What part are you confused about? Yes, `( <View style={style}> )` is definitely JSX-specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code is exporting a [stateless functional component](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#functional-and-class-components).

It's an anonymous es6 [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) with [object 
destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring) of the parameter it receives.

It could also be written like this:

```
const YourComponent = props => {
  const { style } = props;
  return (
    <View style={style}>...
  );
};
export default YourComponent;
```

To convert to a class based component you can do this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
export default class YourComponent extends Component {
  render () {
    const { style } = this.props;
    return (
      <View style={style}>...
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Indeed, it didn't struck my mind as it was just a single item and shortened to just a parameter. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome! I also got a little stuck on this one the first time, but I use it a lot now.